# React Native Navigation Between Two Screen

Tags: npm, react-native, react-navigation

I got these two errors. What should I do?

```
1) PS C:\Users\hp\Test> npm install @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/native-stack
npm WARN jscodeshift@0.11.0 requires a peer of @babel/preset-env@^7.1.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ENOENT   
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\hp\Test\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\react-is
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\hp\Test\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\.react-is.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\hp\Test\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\react-is' -> 'C:\Users\hp\Test\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\.react-is.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-27T09_34_22_863Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\hp\Test>
```

```
2) PS C:\Users\hp\Test> npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
npm WARN jscodeshift@0.11.0 requires a peer of @babel/preset-env@^7.1.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\hp\Test\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\react-is
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\hp\Test\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\.react-is.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\hp\Test\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\react-is' -> 'C:\Users\hp\Test\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\.react-is.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-27T09_24_33_573Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\hp\Test>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was solved when I tried to re-install it again.

```sh
npm install @react-navigation/native-stack

npm install -g react-native-navigation

npm install @react-navigation/native
```